# Getting Access Violation Errors In Different Parts of Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I've been getting these random access violations in our win32 application and have absolutely no idea what could be causing it. I could post code but it's in different parts and would be too long. However, I think I know what the problem could be:

Basically, we have a wndproc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    static ProgramParams params;

    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            params.hwnd = hwnd;
            params.connected = TRUE;
            //more params assignment here
            return 0;

        case WM_RUNTHREADS:
            _beginthread(Func1, 0, &params);
            _beginthread(Func2, 0, &params);
            return 0;

        case WM_DISCONNECT:
            params.connected = FALSE;
            return 0;

// lot more code
}
```

In Func1 and Func2, the pointer to params is used heavily. By heavily, I mean multiple assignments and if statements. I'm not sure if this is a bad idea but I have a feeling that such usage is causing problems. It's like a global variable that connects all the threads together.

Here is also some excerpts of the disassembly:

Unhandled exception at 0x77c815ee in dc final v2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

```
    return TRUE;
001E3AE5  mov         eax,1  
}
001E3AEA  push        edx  
001E3AEB  mov         ecx,ebp  
001E3AED  push        eax  
001E3AEE  lea         edx,[ (1E3B10h)]  
001E3AF4  call        @ILT+220(@_RTC_CheckStackVars@8) (1E10E1h)  
----> 001E3AF9  pop         eax  //green arrow (after clicking "break") pointing here
001E3AFA  pop         edx  
001E3AFB  pop         edi  
001E3AFC  pop         esi  
001E3AFD  pop         ebx  
001E3AFE  add         esp,0E8h  
001E3B04  cmp         ebp,esp  
001E3B06  call        @ILT+610(__RTC_CheckEsp) (1E1267h)  
001E3B0B  mov         esp,ebp  
001E3B0D  pop         ebp  
001E3B0E  ret
```

Assembly around address 0x77c815ee

```
77C815C3  nop  
77C815C4  mov         eax,12Eh  
77C815C9  xor         ecx,ecx  
77C815CB  lea         edx,[esp+4]  
77C815CF  call        dword ptr fs:[0C0h]  
77C815D6  add         esp,4  
77C815D9  ret         18h  
77C815DC  mov         eax,12Fh  
77C815E1  xor         ecx,ecx  
77C815E3  lea         edx,[esp+4]  
77C815E7  call        dword ptr fs:[0C0h]  
----> 77C815EE  add         esp,4 
77C815F1  ret         0Ch  
77C815F4  mov         eax,130h  
77C815F9  xor         ecx,ecx  
77C815FB  lea         edx,[esp+4]  
77C815FF  call        dword ptr fs:[0C0h]  
77C81606  add         esp,4  
77C81609  ret         18h  
77C8160C  mov         eax,131h  
77C81611  xor         ecx,ecx  
77C81613  lea         edx,[esp+4]  
77C81617  call        dword ptr fs:[0C0h]
```

Turning on all Exceptions through Debug > Exceptions results to:

First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in dc final v2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

```
SendMessage(parentHwnd, WM_TERM, (WPARAM) "ABCD", NULL);
001F1CAF  mov         esi,esp  
001F1CB1  push        0  
001F1CB3  push        465h  
001F1CB8  push        402h  
001F1CBD  mov         eax,dword ptr [pparams]  
001F1CC0  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
001F1CC2  push        ecx  
001F1CC3  call        dword ptr [__imp__SendMessageW@16 (1FE68Ch)]  
----> 001F1CC9  cmp         esi,esp //green arrow here
001F1CCB  call        @ILT+610(__RTC_CheckEsp) (1F1267h)
```

I'm really sorry if this is too vague but I'm not sure how else to describe this. I'll be watching this thread like a hawk so if you need anything, let me know.

Even if it's just a "probably caused by not assigning a variable" kind of thing, I'll be glad to hear it as I have no idea where to start looking right now.

Thank you!

Comment: You could run your code through a tool which could analyze for memory overites and corruption,most likely your problem is of that nature resulting in Undefined Behavior.Also, pay attention to warnings emitted by your compiler.

Comment: have you tried running your functions without sharing the parameter? that way you can see if that is causing the issue. i.e. give each an own copy for testing.

Comment: @Als Is there a free tool that you could recommend? I raised warning to /Wall and reviewed each one of them, didn't see anything bad at all.

Comment: Rational purify had a free version of plugin for MSVC AFAIR. try searching for that.

Comment: race on params sounds very plausible explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting random access violations in various parts of the code, your heap is most likely being corrupted.

These errors are very hard to find. To start off, I would suggest downloading Debugging Tools for Windows and using Application Verifier with full heap checking enabled. Be sure to attach a debugger (either Visual Studio's or windbg), as it will raise an exception when the heap corruption occurs.

After that, the only thing you can really do is look through all of the code for anything that looks suspicious. Make sure every pointer is initialized and you aren't accessing any arrays or containers out of bounds.

If multiple threads are writing to the same shared object in parallel, it's possible that it could be corrupted. Try putting a lock around all accesses to the shared object, especially if it has any pointers or data associated with indices.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you have a static `ProgramParams`.  This is definitely going to cause issues if the `Func1` and `Func2` threads start accessing it and it is being written to by the main thread.  You need to either:

1) Create two copies of `ProgramParams` to pass to `Func1` and `Func2`.  Note that this would need to be on the heap and not the stack.

2) Make `ProgramParams` thread-safe using critical sections.